# jQuery Mobile Show/Hide Form input based on select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, toggle, forms

I have the following form fields on my jQuery Mobile page. I want to initially hide the  element, and then have it .show() if the user selects the option with value="Other"

Here's my HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="no-field-separator">
        <select name="plan_height" id="plan_height" data-native-menu="false">
          <option>Plan Height</option>
          <option value="Standard 6foot 2inch">Standard 6'2"</option>
          <option value="Other">Specify in Notes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="specify_plan_height_box" style="display:none;">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label no-field-separator">
          <label for="specify_plan_height">Specify Plan Height</label>
          <input type="text" id="specify_plan_height" name="specify_plan_height" placeholder="Specify Plan Height" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

and here's my JS INSIDE the page:

```
 // $( '#machine-guarding-page' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event) {
$( document ).bind( "pageinit", function( event, data ) {
    $('#plan_height').change(function() {
        var planHeightVal = $("#plan_height option:selected").val();
        var sphb          = $("#specify_plan_height_box");

        sphb.hide();
        if (planHeightVal == "Other") {
            sphb.show();
        }
    });
});
    });
```

It works fine here in this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qe6G4/). Do I need to have something other than  `$(".page").live('pageinit', function() {`
at the top of my JS code to make it work after the page loads? It works fine in the example link above, but not on my jQuery Mobile site.

Comment: Where do I put that JS? and does it need `$(".page").live('pageinit', function() {` or anything with it?

Comment: Crap I didn't mean to edit your comment. Can you put it back? Here's the fiddle you made: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qe6G4/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Qe6G4/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Qe6G4/2/ (optimized)
- http://jsfiddle.net/Qe6G4/3/ (with another input)

Comment: It works in the fiddle, but not on my site. Where do I put this JS? In my attached script.js file? or in the actual document? And, does it need anything before it like `$(".page").live('pageinit', function()` ??

Comment: if you put in in the attached .js file what happens? Made an update: http://jsfiddle.net/Qe6G4/4/

Comment: I updated my code at the top to what I have currently. (the form changed a bit as well). The select box works, but does not show/hide the text box.

Comment: I updated the code at the top to the working version. Thanks so much!! I had to include the code inside the actual page inside of `<script>` tags